# Script running into an infinite loop while trying to insert a character

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of this symbol **'** (Single inverted comma) with **\'** (A slash and an inverted comma).
**I want to ignore the first and the last inverted comma**.

To put it in an another way, I am simply trying to insert a slash before the **'**

**Sample input**: 'hello's world's'
**Expected output**: 'hello\'s world\'s'

I have written the following code but it seems to run into an infinite loop when I execute it.

What am I doing wrong?

And is there a more efficient way of getting it done?

```
text = "'hello's world's'";    
for(i=text.indexOf("'") ; i<text.lastIndexOf("'");i++ )
{ 
  if(text[i]=="'")
  {
    text=text.substr(0,i)+ "\\" + text.substr(i);

    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid using loop and achieve your result with regex. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40550014/7063373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems...

First, you're starting at the index of the first quote, which you claim you want to skip.  So instead of starting with:

```
i=text.indexOf("'")
```

start with:

```
i=text.indexOf("'") + 1
```

Second, and more to the point of the infinite loop, every time you add a character the last index of the last quote increases by 1.  So you're forever adding slashes to the first quote and pushing the last quote further away.

So after the first loop it's:

```
"'hello\'s world's'"
```

then:

```
"'hello\\'s world's'"
```

then:

```
"'hello\\\'s world's'"
```

And so on, infinitely.

To address this, simply increment `i` *again* any time you encounter a match:

```
text=text.substr(0,i)+ "\\" + text.substr(i);
i++;
```

The idea here is that because you've *modified* the string, you need to further modify your placeholder in the string (`i`) to compensate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I now understand where was I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you can do that with `replace()` function:

```
text.replace(/'/g,"\\'");
```

however since you want to ignore the first and the last inverted comma, try the following code:

```
text = "'hello's world's'";
first = text.indexOf("'");
last = text.lastIndexOf("'");
for (i=0; i < text.length - 1; i++)
{

  if (text[i] == "'" && i != first && i != last)
  {
        text = text.substr(0,i) + "\\" + text.substr(i);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: because i need to keep the first and the last inverted commas intact

Answer (score 2):

Here i am trying to check for the charecter if it is "'" then just adding "\" infront of it .I have taken a newarray for the result.

Each time i would slice the array,intially from 0 to index of ''' and add "//" to this sliced string,next slicing index increases from previous index of"'"+1 to current index of "'" ,this continues till the length of the string

```js
var text = "'hello's world's'";
var delimeter = "\\";
var result = "";
var newindex = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  if (text[i] == "'") {
    var str = text.slice(newindex, i);
    result += "\\" + str;
    newindex = i + 1;
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Regex help a lot in this case.

```
text = "'hello's world's'";    
newText = text.replace(/(?!^)'(.*?)(?!$)/g,"\\'");
console.log(newText);
```

Here's regex tester - https://regex101.com/r/9BXvYR/1

**The regex excludes first and last matches of ' and includes every ' in between**

And here's the plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/eTqQ3fK9ELFyRNexGtJI?p=preview